# VueJS - Access multiple data within one methods

Tags: vue.js, methods, data-binding

I'm pretty new in Vue and I'm trying to write down a function that returns `true` or `false` on a given data when input modified. I have 4 different data that I need possibly to change the truthiness.

My logic was to produce a function that accepts data as parameter but... It doesn't work. Maybe it's not the proper way to go for...

Here the HTML:

```
<input type="text" v-model="bannerContent.button" @input="checkMaxChar(48,bannerContent.button.length,isButtonTooLong)" id="banner-button">
```

And the JS

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    bannerContent: {
      title : 'Title',
      text: 'Text',
      copyright: 'Copyright',
      button: 'Button'
    },
    isButtonTooLong: false,
  },
  methods: {
    checkMaxChar: function(a,b,c) {
      var vm = this
      if( a < b ) {
        vm.c = true;
      };
      console.log(this.c);
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are doing `var vm = this` and also where do you defined `c`?

for your purpose define c in the data section like code below and work wit your input:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <input
        type="text"
        v-model="bannerContent.button"
        @input="checkMaxChar(48,bannerContent.button.length,isButtonTooLong)"
        id="banner-button"
      />
    </div>
  </body>
  <script>
    var app = new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
        bannerContent: {
          title: "Title",
          text: "Text",
          copyright: "Copyright",
          button: "Button",
        },
        isButtonTooLong: false,
        c: false,
      },
      methods: {
        checkMaxChar(a, b, c) {
          if (a < b) {
            this.c = true;
          }
          console.log(this.c);
        },
      },
    });
  </script>
</html>
```

Hope it helps You ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read that defining `this` into `vm`var was a good practise. Maybe it isn't. About the definition of `c` it is defined into the `@input` of my input field: `@input="checkMaxChar(48,bannerContent.button.length,isButtonTooLong)`